# how to write this logic in DAX?

Tags: dax, ssas-tabular, msbi

I want to add a new column to my table as `[lastmonth]`. I want last fiscal month where TPH has values comparing from last month in that `projectid` or group by `projectid`.

please give this logic in DAX Query.

[image: This image contains output which we are expecting.]

Comment: @Alexis Olson, Please send the logic in DAX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this as a new calculated column:

```
Last Fiscal Month =
    MAXX(
        FILTER(Table1,
            Table1[projectid] = EARLIER(Table1[projectid]) &&
            Table1[TPH] <> 0),
        Table1[Fiscal Month])
```

Comment: thanks for query , it's working but its getting last month data in every project, but I need last month where TPH generated value

Comment: "=MAX(fiscalmonth) where TPH <> 0 partition by projectid " please check this query , if this query will work please send this query in DAX. This will help me very much

Comment: It works for me. If it's not working for you, show me a screenshot of what you are seeing.

Comment: Where do i add screenshot here, there is no option. please suggest option.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this new column in DAX

```
Last Fiscal =
MAXX (
    FILTER (
        SELECTCOLUMNS (
            Table,
            "ProjId", Table[projectid],
            "FMonth", Table[Fiscal Month],
            "The TPH", Table[TPH]
        ),
        [The TPH] <> 0
            && [ProjId] = Table[projectid]
    ),
    [FMonth]
)
```

Regards,